# python :TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python-3.x

I got this error when I  was trying to run the python script below.It's supposed to transfer a string argument into a float argument，for example,it's supposed to be able to transfer '123.456' to 123.456.I dont't know why I got this error.

```
from functools import reduce
def char2num(s1):
    if s1 == '.':
        pass
    else:
        return  {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9}[s1]

def str2float(s):
    count = 0

    ans = reduce(lambda x, y: 10*x + y,map(char2num,s))

    for x in range(len(s)):
        if s[x] == '.':
            count = x
            break
        else:
            pass
    for n in range(count):
        ans /= 10
    return ans
print('str2float(\'123.456\') =', str2float('123.456'))
```

Comment: when s1="." you don't return anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'm assuming that you know that it can be done with 1 line:

```
str2float = lambda x : float(x)
```

or even by renaming the `float` *function* (so why defining `str2float` in the first place?):

```
str2float = float
```

Let's put that aside now and focus on your problem:

You cannot let a `None` or anything non-digit entering into `reduce`. You have to filter the dot before, for instance like this:

```
ans = reduce(lambda x, y: 10*x + y,map(char2num,filter(lambda x:x!='.',s)))
```

full code:

```
from functools import reduce
def char2num(s1):
    return  {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9}[s1]

def str2float(s):
    count = 0

    ans = reduce(lambda x, y: 10*x + y,map(char2num,filter(lambda x:x!='.',s)))

    for x in range(len(s)):
        if s[x] == '.':
            count = x
            break
        else:
            pass
    for n in range(count):
        ans /= 10
    return ans
print('str2float(\'123.456\') =', str2float('123.456'))
```

result:

```
str2float('123.456') = 123.45599999999999
```

(loss of precision due to the multiple divides by ten)

EDIT: your handling of the dot / divisions are sub-optimal: let me propose another approach, which also works if the float doesn't contain any dot. Compute the index of the dot using standard `index` function and divide by the 10th power of the position to avoid floating point inaccuracy:

```
from functools import reduce
def char2num(s1):
    return  {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9}[s1]

def str2float(s):
    count = 0

    ans = reduce(lambda x, y: 10*x + y,map(char2num,filter(lambda x:x!='.',s)))

    if "." in s:
        dotpos = s.index(".")
    ans /= 10**dotpos

    return ans
print('str2float(\'123.456\') =', str2float('123.456'))
```

result:

```
str2float('123.456') = 123.456
```